# Relations on the power set of $X=\{a,b,c\}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

$$R=\{(A,B) | \ \ |A|=|B|\} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ S=\{(A,B)| \ \ |A|<|B|\}.$$

Are $S$ and $R$ equivalence relations ?

Can someone help me in writing a proof for this? Like I have the idea that $R$ is an equivalence relation and S is not through the general relation and set knowledge but how to give a formal proof of it?

Comment: You ask how to give a formal proof of it. Maybe a good way to start is an informal proof. Which one of the three properties that $S$ needs to have in order to be an equivalence relation does it fail to have?

Comment: "Can someone help me in writing a proof for this? "  A proof of what.  That they *are* equivalence relationships?  That they aren't? That S is and R isn't? Or that R is and S isn't?  You can't prove a *question*.  You can prove an *answer* but you can't prove a question.

Comment: Where do you have trouble?  It's pretty obvious that $S$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, and $S$ is not reflexive, not symmatric, and is transitive.  Where do you have issues proving those.  Just take the the definitons of relflexive, symmetric, and transitive are and .... apply them.  Where are you having trouble.

Comment: To get you started.  Here is reflexive.  If $A\subset X$ then $|A| = |A|$ so $(A,A) \in R$ so $R$ is reflexive.... If $A\subset X$ then $|A| = |A|$ so $|A| < |A|$ is not true.  So $(A,A)\not \in S$ and $S$ is not reflexive.  .... That's *all* you have to do.

Comment: I think @fleablood that a student might well be misled by the distracting information that $X$ is a set of $3$ elements. It's a bad-taste problem.

Comment: @ancientmathematician How so?  Oh... I guess you are saying its seems that *this* particular $X$ as opposed to any *other* set might have something particular to do with this.  The fact that $X$ has three elements *is* irrelevent.  The result is the same for *any* set $X$, finite or infinite, or uncountable. (Even empty, but empty would be a bit abstract.)

Comment: @fleablood Exactly, and although it's a real-life skill to know what's irrelevant and ignore it I think that that this is a beginners' question and shouldn't supply irrelevant information.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Fair enough.  On the other hand maybe that thought this was small enough not to be overwhelming. $|A| = 0,1,2,3$ so it not over whelming to think of cases.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that something is an equivalence relation, you will need to verify the corresponding properties from the definition. A,B, and C are any elements of the given set.

1. **Reflexivity:** A ~ A
2. **Transitivity:** A ~ B and B ~ C implies A ~ C
3. **Symmetry:** If A ~ B then B ~ A

I will show you how to prove the second property:
If A~B and B~C, then |A| = |B| and |B| = |C| by the definition of your first relation. Therefore we have |A| = |C|. By the definition of the relation the last equality means that A ~ C, which is what we needed to prove.

To prove that something is an order relation you will have to verify slightly different properties. All of them can however be verified in a similar way as shown above.

Comment: The answer is fine, but I am always confused by the terminology "order relation". Can you say what it means here?

Comment: An order relation is a relation which is reflexive, transitive, and antisymetric. However they seem to not be directly relevant to the question asked. It's my bad if they created some confusion.

Comment: Thank you. So that's the same as a partial order.